# Munin: Service 'fw_conntrack' timed out

Tags: timeout, munin

Since a few hours the fw_conntrack plugin in munin gives always timeout error.

[image]

It looks like the timeout is just because it took too much time to process, as it had happened a few times before in the graph. Is it normal that this plugin take more than 10 seconds to finish? There is a Varnish which proxies http request to a nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a test:

```
jcisio@cecile:~$ time sudo cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack | wc -l
64218

real    0m13.165s
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m13.129s
```

It takes 13 seconds just to count the number of lines in this file. So munin could not do better. I have to increase the timeout limit.

Comment: How do you increase the timeout limit? Your answer would be more useful if you added that.

Comment: Check the timeout option in munin-node.conf.